# Wearable sleep aid

Tags: smart-device

I struggle to wake up in the morning (who doesn't?) but I've had some success using sleep tracking apps on my phone that wake you up in the right cycle.

However, I don't like leaving my phone on the bed - I'm paranoid it's going to fall off - plus I sleep with my significant other so I'm sure there's some interference as she moves too. I've been interested in getting a smartwatch for a bit.

I read about a smartwatch that wakes you up by vibrating, which feels like a light tap on the wrist (but I don't remember what watch that was). I'm looking for a wearable that can do that and also track your sleep.

What smartwatch would you recommend that I can wear comfortably sleeping that functions well as a sleep tracker and wakes you up pleasantly and reliably? I'm willing to spend a bit on it, somewhere in the $200-300 range.

Comment: Could you explain what solutions you have tried? (Including non-hardware such as sleeping earlier etc)

Comment: @fabriced I actually get a pretty good amount of sleep, and sleep well every night, I just struggle waking up, no matter how much sleep I've had. I'm hoping tactile feedback instead of auditory might help me wake up more quickly, which is why I'm asking after a wearable. Having it track my sleep and wake me up dynamically would be doubleplus good.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is that there is a reason why you are having problems waking up that you might want to investigate before resorting to technology. I would resort to technology only in the last resort... oversleeping can be due to your diet, a health issue not diagnosed or external conditions. In the long run you'd want to know what causes it rather than a quick fix.

Comment: @fabriced I appreciate your concern, but I don't think I have a serious issue. It doesn't take me any longer to get up than my fiancee, or anyone else except those that wake up right away. I'm just providing a little background on my motivation.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm still curious to know what you have tried so far. It might be important to inform your doctor since some of the solutions in the answers (ie Pavlok) can have serious health side effects

Comment: @fabriced I haven't tried much beyond the sleep tracker, which did help. It's probably mostly a combination of an irregular schedule (student) and my tendency to undereat when I'm stressed. Maybe I will chat with my doctor. Nevertheless, I'm also interested in a watch to wake me up so it doesn't disturb my fiancee when we don't get up at the same time. It can't be worse than an alarm, after all.

Comment: Although maybe there are some sound frequencies that you can hear but she can't! Have you tried a solution like the philips wake up light?

Comment: @fabriced Lol perhaps. I've thought about it but it's a large price tag for something I'm not sure if it'll work. At least a smart watch does other things if it doesn't wake my up well

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for something to get you up there is Pavlok.  This literally zaps you awake.  It has a lot of mixed reviews but some people swear by it. Company Website: www.pavlok.com / I recommend checking out the amazon reviews.  They are VERY VERY MIXED>

If you are looking for something that actually tracks your sleep cycle there is a product called sleep cycle that tracks your sleep through a monitor on your night stand.  Has tons of great reviews on Apple and Android platforms.  [Itunes App & Reviews](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sleep-cycle-alarm-clock/id320606217?mt=8) / [Android App & Reviews](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.northcube.sleepcycle&hl=en) / Company Website: www.sleepcycle.com

If you are dead set on a wearable you really do not have much choice out there.  While many of the wearable track your sleep. Ie Fitbit Jawbone Etc.  Most do not wake you up they just give you your sleep data.

After doing more research it seems as though the Jawbone Up2 /3 /4 all offer a "Smart Alarm" That will wake you up inside a 30 minute window https://jawbone.com/up/trackers

Comment: Hmm interesting idea but I really want something that wakes me up nicely, not rudely.

Comment: Did you see the second device?  It will wake you up it is just not a wearable.

Comment: Did you see the updated adding jawbone?