# Sleep tracker wearable/wristband

Tags: smart-device, wearable-technology

I'm looking for a wearable, preferred a wristband, to track my sleep cycles and wake me up (silently) at the best time according to what it tracks about me.

If it has other features, such as activity/fitness tracking - cool, but that it won't be a must to wear it all day.

Side/on bad trackers won't be very useful for me, since I live with my girlfriend and so we sleep together in the same bad. So it shouldn't be distracted by other people in the room.

I checked [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6332/wearable-sleep-aid), but it's a year and a half old, so maybe there are new things on the market that I'm not aware of.

Any recommendations, or [jawbone](https://jawbone.com/up/trackers) is still the best and maybe the only choice for that? How about the [Mi Band](https://www.mi.com/en/miband/)? Thanks!

Comment: Had terrible experiences with Jawbone build quality and customer support, I recommend looking elsewhere.

Comment: @jcam3 Thanks for your comment, I've missed that - the problem with the build quality was for a specific model, or you heard about it for more than one model?

Comment: had unresolved issues with the 2 and 3

Comment: @arieljannai Have you found a device that satisfies your needs? I am looking for the same exact thing but all the mixed Amazon reviews I am seeing about different products are so disappointing.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Unfortunately not yet, but I ordered the Mi band 3 in this Black Friday, and will update what it worth. It's pretty chip so I could test it even without any strong recommendation.

Comment: @arieljannai thanks! And please do share your experience with the device you've ordered. I'm desperate in my searches of a usable _smart_ (sleep cycle driven) and _silent_ wearable alarm.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of searching online I found a device I'm going to give a shot. [Withings Pulse HR](https://www.withings.com/us/en/pulse-hr) seems to match the functionality expectations. Feels a bit pricy for the quality (based on the reviews), however.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice! True it seems a bit pricy - hope it will be good, and I'd like a feedback after trying, if you can :)